# Pos Tag using UIMAFIT in UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

I've tried to implement OpenNlpTagger via Uima Ruta. The process ran without any exception. When I try to open the output file, It's showing Editor could not be initialized.

**Error Message:**

Caused by: XCASParsingException: Error parsing XCAS or XMI-CAS from source  at line , column : **unknown type: de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.metadata.type.TagsetDescription.**
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.XmiCasDeserializer$XmiCasDeserializerHandler.createException(XmiCasDeserializer.java:1635)

**Sample Code:**

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;
IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos 
FROM desc.type.POS AS pos;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Lemma FROM 
desc.type.LexicalUnits;

UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp.OpenNlpSegmenter;
UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp.OpenNlpPosTagger;

uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation{-CONTAINS(pos.POS)} -> {
uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation{-> SETFEATURE("language", "en")};
EXEC(OpenNlpSegmenter);
EXEC(OpenNlpPosTagger);   
};
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
org.apache.uima.UIMARuntimeException
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:368)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:312)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:193)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:218)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.DocumentUimaImpl.setContent(DocumentUimaImpl.java:248)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.DocumentUimaImpl.<init>(DocumentUimaImpl.java:100)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.ide.DefaultCasDocumentProvider.createDocument(DefaultCasDocumentProvider.java:405)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.TextDocumentProvider.createDocument(TextDocumentProvider.java:78)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDocumentProvider.createElementInfo(AbstractDocumentProvider.java:333)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.TextDocumentProvider.createElementInfo(TextDocumentProvider.java:110)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDocumentProvider.connect(AbstractDocumentProvider.java:400)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4233)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:237)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.AnnotationEditor.doSetInput(AnnotationEditor.java:837)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3220)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:371)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2181)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2177)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3238)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3265)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.AnnotationEditor.init(AnnotationEditor.java:594)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:361)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:319)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: XCASParsingException: Error parsing XCAS or XMI-CAS from source <unknown> at line <unknown>, column <unknown>: unknown type: de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.metadata.type.TagsetDescription.
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.XmiCasDeserializer$XmiCasDeserializerHandler.createException(XmiCasDeserializer.java:1635)
```

Answer (score 1):

The type `de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.metadata.type.TagsetDescription` is provided by the following Maven artifact:

**DKPro Core version >= 1.11.0:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.dkpro.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>dkpro-core-api-metadata-asl</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version> <!-- adjust version to DKPro Core version you are using -->
</dependency>
```

**DKPro Core version < 1.11.0:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.metadata-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.0</version> <!-- adjust version to DKPro Core version you are using -->
</dependency>
```

I expect that if you make this available to your Ruta project the exception should go away.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by the fact that not all types of annotations present in the CAS file are available in the type system description used to create the CAS object. This is only indirectly related to UIMA Ruta.

There are several options to avoid this problem:

- You can import the type system description in your Ruta script so that is included in the generated type system description of the script which will automatically be used to open the XMI file in the CAS Editor.
- You can just use a different type system description, for example generated with uimaFIT, which contains all types including TagsetDescription.
- You can activate leniently loading in order to ignore unknown types: Preferences -> UIMA Cas Editor -> Annotation Editor -> Load CAS leniently